# Unable to scroll to the bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I know there are many answers of the question in the forum but they didn't help me. Here is my problem.

I have `UITableView` with `UISegmentedControl`. In the one segment there is less data than in the other one. After rotation or segment switch, I invoke `reloadData` to ensure that the entire data is displayed. That works.

Now, the user clicks on a cell and goes to another view using the same `UISegmentedControl`. It is intended that the same control is used, I want that both views show the same perspective to the data. The problem appears when the user sees the perspective with less data on the first screen, goes to the second and changes the perspective to the data there. Then he goes back and is not able to scroll to the bottom of the table. If he rotates the screen or changes the segment, everything is fine again.

I tried solving the problem by implementing `viewWillAppear:` and reducing/calculating there the height of the `tableView`. Unfortunately, it didn't worked. Invoking `reloadData` doesn't help neither. Actually, the `tableView` is already reloaded when switching the segment... But still, I am not able to see the last cells of the table.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Here are the heights that I get from the tests (without resizing):

`NSLog(@"Before switch: %f, %f", self.tableView.frame.size.height, self.tableView.contentSize.height);` --> Before switch: 372.000000, 471.000000

`NSLog(@"After switch: %f, %f", self.tableView.frame.size.height, self.tableView.contentSize.height);` --> After switch: 372.000000, 585.000000

The `tableView` remains the same, only the `contentSize` increases. I tried setting the value of the one to the value of the other, reducing the values etc. but I don't really know what should be done...

**EDIT2:**

All `contentSize` and `height` values seem to be fine. However, I realized that the problem is somehow related to the custom header view on the screen. When I remove it from the table view, it scrolls to the end. With the header view, however, it does not. I don't change anything from the header view, it is just a view with buttons on the top of the table.

Comment: an image of both the views would help.

Comment: show your code when you change size of your tableView

Comment: have you set the height of tableview?

Comment: For the height I tried lastly
`CGRect tableViewFrame = [self.tableView frame];
 tableViewFrame.size.height /= 2;
 [self.tableView setFrame: tableViewFrame];` Before, I was calculating the height also through `bounds` and

Comment: In respect to the image.. there is nothing special in the views, just tables with cells and toolbar containing the segmented control. In the first view there is also another view in the table, just before the cells. But I don't think that matters, its size doesn't change.

Comment: Ok, after multiple tests I found out that everything works fine when I don't have the custom header view on the first screen. Although this remains the same, it somehow blocks the table display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of experiments, I increased the `contentSize.height` property of the `tableView` by one and now everything works fine. I have no idea why that works but it is a solution. By the way, decreasing the property by one leads to the same result. In both cases, the table is correctly displayed.

Comment: Hi Antiohia, I'm facing the same issue, would you post the exact code and where do you call it?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the code anymore. Basically, I simply changed the contentSize height forcing the view to update it. But as of my experience, there are many things that may lead to the problem and changing the height by one is the last solution that I would try, after making sure that all heights are really fine.

Comment: I tried many things, my heights were fine, I ended up changing my design =/

Answer (score 4):

It because your tableView's frame height is exceeding the visible area. Decrease the tableView's frame height to be inside the visible area. You will see everything.

```
tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthYouWant, heightYouWant);
```